# LDAP check if user account is locked/unlocked by ppolicy

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap

**How to check if user account locked or unlocked by ppolicy?**

Here is situation:

1. I have added default ppolicy :

   ```
   dn: cn=default,ou=ppolicies,dc=scb,dc=kz
   objectClass: applicationProcess
   objectClass: pwdPolicy
   cn: default
   pwdAttribute: userPassword
   pwdLockout: TRUE
   pwdMaxFailure: 5
   pwdLockoutDuration: 900
   ```

If ppolicy locked user for **pwdLockoutDuration** seconds (15 minutes) **pwdAccountLockedTime** operational attribute appears.

**It is ok!**

2. At this time user unable to authenticate within 15 minutes. Also I can detect if user is locked by checking if **pwdAccountLockedTime** attribute exists.

**It is ok too!**

3. After 15 minutes ppolicy unlocks user account and user can log in, but unless the user log in **pwdAccountLockedTime** attribute still exists.

**Is there any other way to find out if the user has been already automatically unlocked by ppolicy after lockout duration**

Answer (score 0):

According to Draft-behera-ldap-password-policy:
section 7.6. Intruder Lockout Check 
A status of true indicating that an intruder has been detected is returned if the following conditions are met:

- The pwdLockout attribute is TRUE.
- The number of values in the pwdFailureTime attribute that are younger
  than pwdFailureCountInterval is greater or equal to the pwdMaxFailure
  attribute.
- otherwise a status of false is returned.

While performing this check, values of pwdFailureTime that are old by more than pwdFailureCountInterval are purged and not counted.

However, you do not mention which LDAP implementation you are using and if the implementation is complying to Draft-behera-ldap-password-policy.